# Having problem with multi languages store in magento2

Tags: magento2, language

My problem is that I have three store views and I set three languages view from admin. In frontend when I click on second language it work than i click on third language url it give error and not redirect.

Url: https://telecarsi.de

Please click on language pop twice then it give error i want to switch language.

Comment: now check var/report

Comment: Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#16 \/home\/telecars\/public_html\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#17 {main}","url":"\/?___store=default?___store=english","script_name":"\/index.php"}

Comment: error above comment

Comment: I cant see any error there on language popup

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this problem before. After that I tried this which works fine for me.

Try this -

You can see `languages.phtml` file under `templates/switch` folder.

Replace this code:

```
<a href="#" data-post='<?php echo $this->getTargetStorePostData($_lang); ?>'>
```

With :

```
<a href="<?php echo $_lang->getHomeUrl();  ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Magento 2 issue.

See: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10908

What is you Magento version? It's maybe resolved in latest version 2.2.2.

Comment: I can't comment his answer but Indranil Maity answer's is not a good way to me because it will always redirect to home.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Magento 2.2.0 bug.

To fix it, upgrade to the latest version, or temporarily fix it by changing the `getTargetStorePostData` function in:

> /vendor/magento/module-store/Block/Switcher.php

Change it to:

```
public function getTargetStorePostData(\Magento\Store\Model\Store $store, $data = [])
{
    $data[\Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface::PARAM_NAME] = $store->getCode();
    return $this->_postDataHelper->getPostData(
        //$store->getCurrentUrl(false),
        $this->getUrl('stores/store/switch'),
        $data
    );
}
```